# Issue creating number of sockets one by one in loop

Tags: java, android, sockets, wifi, serversocket

I have made a school app in which teacher sends a string message to the students. Teacher holds a hash-map of logged in students. When Teacher presses next page command in his tablet, students should see the next page. And that is what happens normally, but sometimes when teacher is not able to make connection with a single student in the hash-map for some reason whole process gets very slow and rarely the systems ceases to respond any further.

```
public static void SendToEveryStudent(String message) throws IOException, ELearningException 
{   
    String command;
    String host;
    int port;
    String failedStudents = "";
    int leftOverStudents = 0;
    ApplicationLog.log("Command Queue: sendToEveryStudent : " + message, InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().isLoggingEnabled());
    int socketTimeout;

    Socket studentSocket = null;

    StudentUtility.studentCounter = 0;

    port = InitializeTeacherJar.getGlobalPort();
    socketTimeout = InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().getTeacherStudentSocketTimeout();

    // Check if no of students are more then zero
    if (InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().getStudentIPList().keySet().size() > 0)
    {
        StudentUtility.studentCounter = InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().getStudentIPList().keySet().size();

        for (String key : InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().getStudentIPList().keySet())
        {
            try 
            {   
                host = InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().getStudentIPList().get(key).get(0);

                if (!host.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                {   
                    if (studentSocket != null)
                    {
                        studentSocket.close();
                        studentSocket = null;
                    }

                    try
                    {   
                        studentSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(host), port);
                        studentSocket.setSoTimeout(socketTimeout);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        leftOverStudents++;
                        failedStudents = key + InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().getDelimiter();
                        ApplicationLog.log("Exception :: " + host +" is not reachable as the server is down at his end.", InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().isLoggingEnabled());
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (studentSocket != null)
                    {
                        if (InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().getStudentIPList().get(key).get(1).equalsIgnoreCase("present"))
                        {
                            studentSocket.getOutputStream().write((message + "\n").getBytes());

                            ApplicationLog.log("Command Queue: Message to student :: " + message + " :: " + key, InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().isLoggingEnabled());

                            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(studentSocket.getInputStream()));

                            String line = null;

                            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                            {
                                if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("ack"))
                                {
                                    //ApplicationLog.log("InitializeTeacherJar :: Student Counter is :: " + StudentUtility.studentCounter, InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().isLoggingEnabled());
                                    ApplicationLog.log("Command Queue: Ack recvd for :: "+ key + " :: " + host, InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().isLoggingEnabled());
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    ApplicationLog.log("Command Queue: Did Not received ACK for :: "+ key + " :: " + host, InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().isLoggingEnabled());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            studentSocket.getOutputStream().write((CONSTANTS.ALERT + InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().getDelimiter() + ErrorCodes.TABLET_NOT_ASSIGNED).getBytes());

                            ApplicationLog.log("StudentUtility :: Tablet not assigned to :: " + key, InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().isLoggingEnabled());
                        }

                        studentSocket.close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                ApplicationLog.log("CommandQueue :: sendToEveryStudent Exception :: " + e, InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().isLoggingEnabled());

                studentSocket.close();
            }

            studentSocket = null;
        }
    }

    if (leftOverStudents > 0)
    {
        failedStudents = StudentUtility.m_stripLastChar(failedStudents);

        ApplicationLog.log("SendToEveryStudent :: Some Students Were Not Connected :: " + ErrorCodes.TEACHER_STUDENT_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED + InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().getDelimiter() + failedStudents, InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().isLoggingEnabled());

        InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().getMyFlexSocket().getOutputStream().write((CONSTANTS.ALERT + InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().getDelimiter() + ErrorCodes.TEACHER_STUDENT_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED + InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().getDelimiter() + failedStudents + InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().getCommandDelimeter()).getBytes());
        InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().getMyFlexSocket().getOutputStream().flush();         
    }
    else if (leftOverStudents == 0)
    {
        InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().getMyFlexSocket().getOutputStream().write((CONSTANTS.ALERT + InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().getDelimiter() + CONSTANTS.SENT_SUCCESSFULLY_TO_ALL + InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().getDelimiter() + "Sent To All" + InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().getCommandDelimeter()).getBytes());
        InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().getMyFlexSocket().getOutputStream().flush();
    }

    StudentUtility.studentCounter = StudentUtility.studentCounter - leftOverStudents;
    }
}
```

The area where my apprehensions lies are

1) Loop - loop, which makes the sockets and call the blocking call i.e. accept, should go in a AsynTask.
2) SocketTimeout - it should be bare minimal, right now its 1.2 secs. What is the optimal value for this?

This might be little too much code, but I hope the explanation helps.
Thanking in advance.

Comment: Have you considered storing a list of actual sockets instead of ip addresses? In your situation, I don't think keeping the open sockets would be an issue, as this app appears to be used in one setting - as a student is added, create the socket, when the student leaves, close it. Then you don't have to continually create new connections (which can be time consuming)

Comment: +1 for being one of the best "homework" type questions I've seen

Comment: @Drake Clarris: Thanks. What i have read across WWW is that you cant have myriad sockets open in a android based system, due to constrained memory environment. There d be 40 students logged in at the same time. Would a mobile b able to handle those many open sockets simultaneously? I ve been meaning to do that simulcast thing but could...good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being I have got a shim to be over with it. However I am going to try the "collection of live sockets" thing after I get over with the due release of the software.

Anyways what i have done is following changes to the above code:

```
                try
                {   
                    inAddress = InetAddress.getByName(host);

                    if (!inAddress.isReachable())
                    {
                       leftOverStudents++;
                       failedStudents = key + InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().getDelimiter();
                       ApplicationLog.log("Exception :: " + host +" is not reachable as the server is down at his end.", InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance().isLoggingEnabled());
                       continue; 
                    }

                    studentSocket = new Socket(inAddress, port);
                    studentSocket.setSoTimeout(socketTimeout);
                }
```

All I do is just move to next student if it is not reachable.
Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a backwards setup. Imagine a web server that would go and connect to all potential clients to push a web page - skipping all the NAT/firewall issues that just doesn't scale and is prone to head-of-the-list delays in a sequential single-threaded implementation and to waste of resources in any multi-threaded setup.

I would suggest switching to conventional client-server model where teacher is the server, and students are the clients connecting on demand.

Comment: Hey thanks, have been through this before. For your way, I need to have alive sockets for each student, as students cant poll teacher for commands like next, previous page, submit answers etc so teacher has to ping them all with the command. The project has a huge legacy code base, and documentation from former developer says that concurrent sockets crashed the application (I don't trust that guy though). I haven't tried it yet though.
Have you ever tried having 40+ open sockets at a time?